# White space around css3 scale

Tags: css, scale

I have a small issue I want to fix, but can't find any good answer :

When I use a scale on a div (which contains other divs), it leave white space around, from the "original" width and height of my div :

[image]

How can I remove the withe space around the div while scaled ?

I can use js if needed !

EDIT: Here is some code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="pull-right nextpack">

                    <div class="quarter scale-thumb">

                        <div class="up">
                            <div class="inner" style="background-image: url({{URL::base().'/galery/th293x711/'.$nextpack->src}})"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="face">
                            <div class="top" style="background-image: url({{URL::base().'/galery/th293x711/'.$nextpack->src}})"></div>
                            <div class="bot" style="background-image: url({{URL::base().'/galery/th293x711/'.$nextpack->src}})"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cote-droit">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="cote-droit-top" style="background-image: url({{URL::base().'/galery/th293x711/'.$nextpack->src}})"></div>
                                <div class="cote-droit-bot" style="background-image: url({{URL::base().'/galery/th293x711/'.$nextpack->src}})"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>
```

**CSS**
(you really don't need to know how the pack is done, it's a lot of css3 for nothing, basically just skew, rotate, scale to make a 3D render from a flat template)

```
.quarter.scale-thumb
{
-webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
-moz-transform: scale(0.2);
-o-transform: scale(0.2);
transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

PS : The first pic is when I don't add the scale-thumb class

Comment: Show some relevant code. Question is impossible to answer from a screenshot.

Comment: Is this more clear? The code is no big deal, it's really the scale and the white space around it that keeps me stuck :)

Comment: You could put it all inside another div which has `overflow:hidden`, then resize that div.

Comment: When I add this : 
.nextpack
{
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
 -o-transform: scale(0.2);
 transform: scale(0.2);
}

I still have white space around...

Comment: Adjust the `transform-origin` property, which centers a scaled box vertically and horizontally, by default. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43020800/3597276

Answer (score 37, accepted):

solution is to wrap the element inside a container, and resize it too while the scale() is done

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2KxSJ/

relevant code is:

```
#wrap
{
    background:yellow;
    height:66px;
    width:55px;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;
    /* more transition here */
}

#wrap:hover
{
    height:300px;
    width:260px;
}

.quarter
{
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
    -o-transform: scale(0.2);
    transform: scale(0.2);
    background:red;
    width:250px;
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;
    /* more transition here */
}


#wrap:hover .quarter
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
    -moz-transform-origin:left top;
    /* more transform-origin */
}
```

Comment: his fiddle has dead links, here's an updated fork: http://jsfiddle.net/2KxSJ/243/

Comment: This answer and fiddle are full of extra code. The key point is that the document flow will shift when animating the `height` and `width` of the wrapping element.

Comment: For future readers - the container is specifying the exact width/height for both states. There's nothing special going on here.

Answer (score 41):

how `transform` works is:

1. your element gets rendered
2. your element gets transformed (moved, rotated, scaled)
3. other elements stay where they got rendered - around the "original element"

so the white space is really just the way the element was rendered in the first place.

You should use `width` and `height` in CSS if you want to render the size of elements differently and have the surrounding elements respond to it.

Or you could use something like javascript to resize things.

Comment: Well, I can't do it with width and height because the elements I want to resize are not in percentage, and it's really complicated to make it so.

How would you do it in js ?

Answer (score 6):

I resolved my problem like yours that way.

I have a main container and I want decrease it

my css:
 `.grid-container.full {
        transform: scale(0.6);
        transform-origin: top center;
}`

but my container had the bigger margin bottom.
then I do it:

`$mainGrid = $('.grid-container.full')
$mainGrid.css('height', $mainGrid.height() * .6);`

Comment: the `transform-origin: top center` option was the thing I was missing - my parent container was huge, and it decided to transform from the bottom up - so it created a ton of "white space".

Answer (score 6):

Solved the issue with margin-bottom (it will be negative in case of scaling down):

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#content {
  --scale: 0.5;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
  transform-origin: top left;
  margin-bottom: calc((var(--scale) - 1) * 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Around css-based solutions, I think this one is the most stable

Comment: Good use of var() to keep everything clear and clean also.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem and I solved it in this way, I used SCSS in order to don't repeat the same numbers along the code. The below code just moves the element right as the zoom decreases, in order to re-align it.

```
$originalWidth: 100px;
$rate: 0.5;

parent {
  width: $originalWidth;
}

parent > div {
  transform: scale(1);
}

parent:hover {
  width: $originalWidth*$rate;
}

parent:hover > div {
  transform: translateX(($originalWidth * ($rate - 1))/2) scale($rate); /* the order matters*/
}
```

You can get rid of SCSS just using CSS variables and `calc()`, if you prefer.

Comment: I think the community benefits from reading an explanation as to why that worked, even if it is a small explanation. Not just "Here's my code".

Comment: I think it's self-explanatory, it just pushes the element right as the zoom decreases. I'll add some comment though

Answer (score 2):

Another idea for white spaces when you transform objects

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        transformme
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.outer { overflow:hidden }
.inner {
    transform-origin:left top;
}
```

js

```
var rate = 0.5;
var outerheight = $('.inner').outerHeight()*rate;
$('.inner').css({ transform: "scale("+rate+")" });
$('.outer').css({ height: outerheight });
```

Also you can add other browser tags; -webkit-transform, -moz-transform, -o-transform

Answer (score 2):

it's simple you have to calculate with height, If for some reason you turn it upside down! like here your current `width: 500px;` and `height: 220px;` you want to reverse it like `width: 220px; height: 500px;` then again you have to use `margin-bottom: calc((0.6 - 1) * 500px);` that's it.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 5px solid black;
}

#child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  background: #555; 
  transform: scale(0.6);
  transform-origin: top center;
  margin-bottom: calc((0.6 - 1) * 220px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution: You could put it all inside another div which has `height:0px;`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by positioning my elements in position absolute.Like this, you have full control of the space by playing with the margins and place your elements where you want them.

#element {position: absolute; scale: 0.7;}

Answer (score 0):

try multiplying both width and height of image using decimal numbers. Like this ->
(I used SCSS)

```
img{
 width : 100px * 0.5;  // width reduced to half
 height : 100px * 0.5; // height reduced to half
}
```

I hope this helps in 2021 !

Comment: This will only cause an error in the CSS for the element it won't without using the `calc` function

Answer (score 0):

I had the task to place drop-down into the site menu scaled to 0.5 top right with  width: 500px. I resolved it: wrap drop-down into tag div, then apply next CSS code the wrapper:

```
div.scale_wrapper{
    position: relative;
    top: 34px;
    margin-right: calc(500px * -0.5);
}
```

Play with 34px for your current purposes. -0.5 is scale

Demo link with drop-down in the top site menu: https://demo.currency-switcher.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need Firefox compatibility you could use `{zoom:0.2}` instead of `{transform: scale(0.2);}`

Answer (score -2):

I solved this with by adding an '**outline: 1px solid transparent**' to the element where the scale is applied on.

```
#wrap:hover .quarter
{
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
   -o-transform: scale(0.9);
   transform: scale(0.9);
   -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
   -moz-transform-origin:left top;

   outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but this actually works amazingly in all browsers! How did you get to this?

Comment: Doesn't work, and if it did, it would be nice to know why.

Comment: I removed the outline:1px solid transparent and it still works for me.  All I needed was the origin statements. Beforehand the -transform was scaling all the whitespace and centering the shrunken image so this answer helped me

Comment: This works, just tested and works in JavaScript also - just set the element style:  `.transformOrigin='left top';` .. after this just re-size the element's parent/wrapper by using `.getBoundingClientRect().width` .. (or height) respectively.