# Scale a div in CSS

Tags: html, css, scale

I am facing a problem while scaling a div using CSS. I am using the below CSS to scale a div. But the whole window is getting scaled. 'ScaleOn is the class of that div'

```
div.scaleOn {
transform: scale(2, 5);
-moz-transform: scale(2, 5);
 -ms-transform: scale(2, 5);
-webkit-transform: scale(2, 5);
 -o-transform: scale(2, 5);
}
```

Comment: please provide the html markup. As css is case sensitive, and you've used a Capital letter on one part and a lowercase letter in your definition could be your issue here.

Comment: @jbutler483 I don't think that is the case...I have been able to reproduce his problem in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/401zbr1z/2/). Seems like default behavior if you are scaling divs. Try to inspect the scaled element and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @jbutler483 Class name are same in CSS and Html, by mistake I written in Capital Letter

Comment: possible duplicate of [White space around css3 scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale)

Comment: @Mikey You are right, the wrapped element gives that error. Its solved

Answer (score -1):

I don't know but this topic discusses a similar problem: [White space around css3 scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale)

You must wrap your scaled div inside another div. Hope it helps!