# Scaling down images by media queries doesn't work

Tags: css, media-queries, scale

Experts,
I have a page containing thumbnails:
http://ulrichbangert.de/heimat/Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen/2015-04-05_Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen.php
My intention is to reduce the size of the thumbs to 50% for a small screen so that more of them fit on the screen. I already have a solution by JS but would like to use CSS instead. My latest approach uses scale:
CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
a.th200 {
    -moz-transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform:scale(0.5);
    display: inline-block;   
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="2015-04-05_Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen_01.jpg" class="ilightbox th200"><img class="th200" src="2015-04-05_Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen_01_th200.jpg" alt="Oldtimertreffen in Bad Harzburg"></a>
```

Scaling down works fine so far as Firebug indicates but there is a lot of space between the thumbnails so that the disired effect is not achieved. What causes this empty space? How can I remove it?

Comment: Are you able to use bootstrap? The container columns will respond to the different sized screens and the items inside, if 100% of their parent, will scale down with them.

Comment: This is not the first recommendation for Bootstrap but I would not like to learn the ropes of another framework. If CSS doesn't work I would keep my JS solution.

Comment: Bootstrap is incredibly simple, I promise you. Far simpler than writing the CSS yourself. Just download it, add a couple of classes to your DIV tags, et voila!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a DIV as a container and then a DIV for each thumbnail, and scale the thumbnail DIVs down. If the images inside are 100% the size of the DIV then they will scale down with it. This will eliminate the spaces you are seeing at the moment.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't remove the empty spaces: http://ulrichbangert.de/heimat/Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen/2015-04-05_Bad_Harzburg_Oldtimertreffen_test.php Additionally the layout is no longer line oriented.

Comment: In the meantime I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale When I read Martin Turjaks answer, it seems to me that there is no way to work around the empty spaces.