# CSS scaling and removing whitespace

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that uses images which must all be scaled down by a consistent factor (`0.25`). Like others have pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436403/remove-white-space-after-scale?noredirect=1&lq=1), scaling is an operation that is done *after* the page elements are rendered, resulting in whitespace surrounding the scaled image. I need to get rid of that extra space.

I've read every solution and still can't figure this out. I'm totally fine with a javascript solution—which I still can't figure out—but I can't help but feel there is an alternative to using the scaling element and bypassing javascript altogether.

I could scale all of the original images down using `imagemagick`, but that's a last resort for a number of reasons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .image-container {
        background: #555; 
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        transform: scale(0.25);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here's my first paragraph.</p>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51806458206_1e7ba12389_o.png"><img>
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51805498867_57abd12b23_o.png"><img>
</div>
<p>Here my second paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drfk7xz9/31/. Thank you in advance

Comment: Make sure to fix your html markup for the image tags. `<img src="..." />`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (with javascript)

```js
window.onload = function () {
  resizeImages();
};

function resizeImages() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll("figure > img");
  var originalWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    originalWidth = images[i].naturalWidth;
    images[i].style.width = (originalWidth * 0.25) + "px";
  }
}
```