# How can I remove white spaces in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi Im making a homepage on this link :
http://stephaniie.com/_testlab/beta1/index.html

I Love to know how to remove these stupid white lines. 
Can someone please help?

Edit: I tried to use this method by Michael.

I changed html - div to " quarter.scale-thumb " and added in CSS.

```
.quarter.scale-thumb {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
     -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
     -o-transform: scale(0.2);
     transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

Didnt work :(

The code Im using in minimap.css is:

```
.minimap {
    z-index:10000;
    position:fixed;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 0em;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}

.miniregion {
    z-index : 10001;
    position : fixed;
    background : transparent;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}

.miniregion.dragging {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    display:block;
        padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}

.miniregion:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 .400em darkgrey;
    display:block;
        padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -khtml-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Which white lines? Can not see any.

Comment: in the minimap . Its to the right.

Comment: Can't see any white-spaces either

Comment: The `transform: scale()` is creating that distortion when it renders the images. Toggle that in dev tools and it goes away. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale

Comment: https://snag.gy/SQNzba.jpg

Comment: how do I toggle in dev tools? 
thats like greek to me :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker DO I need the HTML code too.. or just css?

I edited it like this...
HTML . changed div to "quarter.scale-thumb" and added CSS . .quarter.scale-thumb
{
-webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
-moz-transform: scale(0.2);
-o-transform: scale(0.2);
transform: scale(0.2);
}

Comment: Didnt really understand that soluytion @MichaelCoker . 

Should i use that code in a <style> tag ? and change name of the div to "wrap" ?

Comment: I added that code .. it turned my page : http://stephaniie.com/_testlab/beta1/index.html into a rollercoaster :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS

```
img[usemap] {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 95%; //change from auto to 95%
}

.back{
background-color : #fffee0; //add background color
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="toolbar-options" class="back" >
```

Comment: Didnt sadly work . but It could be im using jQuery 1.1 . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It simple css, not linked with jQuery. Working on my side. http://imgur.com/C0WM2ty

Comment: http://stephaniie.com/_testlab/beta1/ - using it. Still have white stripes. but it could be some other fault im missing :)