# Flexbox justify-content not working properly with transform scale

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transforms

I have a regular unordered list of items with `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` applied to it (as a result, `.first_item` touches the left edge of `.list` and `.last_item` touches the right edge of `.list`):

```
<ul class='list'>
    <li class='first_item'>Item</li>
    <li class='middle_item'>Item</li>
    <li class='last_item'>Item</li>
</ul>
```

However, if I shrink the items using `transform: scale(0.5)`, there is now a space at these two locations, as if `justify-content: space-between` was "unaware" that the items have been reduced.

This isn't right: even when shrinking the items, the first and last item should still touch the left and right edges of the container.

What's going on and how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you scale down the element with the `transform`, it is automatically centered within its box.

This is because the initial value of the [**`transform-origin`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property) property is `50%, 50%` (i.e., centered horizontally and vertically).

As a result, the items are offset from the edges of the container.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='first_item'>Item</li>
  <li class='middle_item'>Item</li>
  <li class='last_item'>Item</li>
</ul>
```

You can adjust the position of the transformed element with `left` and `right` on `transform-origin`.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.first_item {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.last_item {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: right;
}

li {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class='first_item'>Item</li>
  <li class='middle_item'>Item</li>
  <li class='last_item'>Item</li>
</ul>
```

More details in the spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property

Comment: Your answer seems to work for a case where you only have 3 items, However if you have more items in the flexbox you the spacing between the items in the center will be smaller than the space between a center and border element since the flexbos really doesn't calculate with the scale transform property.

Comment: Is there anyway to force the flexbox to recalculate after the scale transform?  This is exactly what I'm struggling with, I'd like the flexbox width and height to be calculated from after the scale transform