# How to reduce whole size wihtout affecting the image visiblity?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am doing a image puzzle using jquery, I have done every thing but, the cropped image size is very bigger (cropped original size), when the user select the 2x2 puzzle. So I want to reduce the size of the cropped image, but when I reduce the the width & height it affect the image visibility area. But I want to reduce the size without affecting the image.

```
 <div style="background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kEf8bQ/rhyms1.jpg);background-position: 0px 0px;background-size:1000px;border:1px solid red;width:500px; height:281px;float:left"></div>
```

Link is https://jsfiddle.net/xpon67bw/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `transform: scale(0.5);` css property.

You need to add browser prefix to the transform property for it to work on all devices for more information on browser compatibility of transform property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=control#Browser_compatibility

Here, you can get more information on transform css property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform

For more information on scale

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

**UPDATE:**

To remove white space around the scaled image you can set origin of the transform.

```
-webkit-transform-origin:left top;
-moz-transform-origin:left top;
 transform-origin:left top;
```

This will align the scaled image to the left top of the box.

After a element is rendered if you transform an element
other elements stay where they got rendered around the original element.

To remove this side effect you need to wrap your transformed element inside a div and resize it as and when you transform the element. Doing this will re-render all the elements around the transformed element.

For more information on how to do this checkout this stack-overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale).

**SNIPPET**

```css
#bg-image{
     background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kEf8bQ/rhyms1.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 281px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
    -moz-transform-origin:left top;
    transform-origin:left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-image"></div>
```

**UPDATE-2**

To achieve what you are trying to do

**HERE IS A JS-FIDDLE SHOWING A PUZZLE CHECKOUT.**

https://jsfiddle.net/nmgcq52s/7/

Comment: @MerbinJoe You can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: But the div take whole width and height how can consider the scaled image size and width?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is working, but only for left and top, please see this screen shot https://image.ibb.co/jXXobQ/updated.png

Comment: @MerbinJoe could you please share the complete code as jsfiddle would be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: @MerbinJoe checkout the Update-1. I have added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual image width is `640px` and you set it's width `1000px` that's why it's visibility.

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kEf8bQ/rhyms1.jpg);background-position: 0px 0px;background-size:640 auto;border:1px solid red;width:300px; height:281px;float:left"></div>
```

Comment: for puzzle only Im cropping the image

Comment: @MerbinJoe then you have to used big size image instead of small image

Comment: transform: scale(0.5); this was solved my problem. Now I can use this in big size or small size. Thanks for answering

Comment: @MerbinJoe `transform: scale(0.5);` gives extra space around your object. you can test it before using..